# which are the basic type of cursors in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I want to know basic type FAST_FORWARD in cursor.what is its use?
what is the purpose of the statement SET       @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD in sql

Comment: I'm not aware of any database with a syntax that allows `SET @CursorVariable = CURSOR ...`. If they're SQL compliant, they should use `DECLARE @CursorVaraible CURSOR ...`. So far as I'm aware, `FAST_FORWARD` is only in SQL Server dialect - so what RDBMS are you using? (I see there's been a tag fight between having `mysql` and `sql-server` on this question)

Comment: Why don't you try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172375.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking about FAST_FORWARD, I'm assuming you're working with SQL-Server.
A cursor can be configured in several ways:

- `FORWARD_ONLY` - This is the default configuration - it allows the cursor to run from first to last and allows updates through the cursor.
- `READ_ONLY` - Does not allow updates through the cursor (improves performance)
- `FAST FORWARD` - Combination of FAST_FORWARD and READ_ONLY

Two other important options are:

- `LOCAL`- The cursor can only be accessed within the cursor's scope and the cursor is implicitly deallocated when the batch, stored procedure, or trigger terminates.
- `GLOBAL` - Specifies that the scope of the cursor is global to the connection. The cursor name can be referenced in any stored procedure or batch executed by the connection. The cursor is only implicitly deallocated at disconnect.

Full documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).